# ¿Por qué se corta el ticket hasta el tamaño de hoja carta mas o menos siendo una impresora térmica?

Tags: java

Aquí les dejo el código que tengo para que imprima todo imprime perfectamente pero cuando el ticket es mas largo que una hoja de tamaño carta ya no sale lo demás ¿A que se debe?.

En la parte de pasajeros crezco la tabla y el formulario de acuerdo al numero de pasajeros que viajan todo lo hace bien pero ya cuando son mas o menos arriba de 50 pasajeros el ticket no se imprime completo se corta hasta el tamaño mas o menos de una hoja tamaño carta les dejo al final las fotos donde se aprecia la impresión.

```
public guia() {
    setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("autobus.png")).getImage());
    initComponents();
    this.pasaj = logistica.pasajeros;
    pasajeros();
}

public void pasajeros(){
 if(this.pasaj <= 10 ){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 373);
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 124);
    }else if (this.pasaj >= 11 && this.pasaj <=20){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 448);
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 194);
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 21 && this.pasaj <=30){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 548); 
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 294);
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 31 && this.pasaj <=40){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 648);  
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 394);
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 41 && this.pasaj <=50){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 748); 
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 494);           
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 51 && this.pasaj <=60){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 848); 
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 594);    
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 61 && this.pasaj <=70){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 948); 
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 694);    
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 71 && this.pasaj <=80){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 1048); 
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 794);    
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 81 && this.pasaj <=90){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 1148); 
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 894);    
    }else if(this.pasaj >= 91 && this.pasaj <=100){
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 222, 1248); 
    guia.tabla_guia.setSize(201, 994);    
    }
    
}

public void imprime(){
 int margin = 0;
    String ticket = null;
    String output = ticket;
    JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
    jtp.setText(output);
    jtp.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, 0 , 8));    
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pageFormat = printerJob.defaultPage();        
    Paper paper = new Paper();      
    //paper.setSize(180.0, (double) (paper.getHeight() + lines * 10.0));
    paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - margin * 2, paper.getHeight() - margin * 2);
    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);        
    pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    printerJob.setPrintable(jtp.getPrintable(null, null), pageFormat);
    try {
        printerJob.setPrintable(this, pageFormat);
        printerJob.printDialog();
        printerJob.print();
        dispose();
        //printerJob.printDialog();    
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(boleto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

[image: como pueden ver en la aplicacion si se ve el ticke completo con el total pero al imprimir sale como en la segunda imagen mocho]

[image: asi es como sala al imprimir mochado el total como si el limite fuera una hoja tamaño carta siendo los ticket mas pequeños salen perfectamente saben a que se debe?]

Comment: Creo que el problema vas mas por la configuración de la impresora que por tu código. Has probado tu programa en otra impresora? Has verificado las "Preferencias de Impresion" y "Propiedades de impresion" ?

Comment: si de echo ya cale con dos impresoras diferente modelo y hacen lo mismo si busque tambien ya en las propiedades de la impresora y no encontre solucion, siento que es en el pageformat algun codigo para que no limite a una hoja de altura la verdad no tengo idea me sigo documentando igual se agradece